# Word for veneration due to moral example

Tags: single-word-requests

some time ago I read this word that meant, approximately, when something is a moral example and was worshipped because of that reason.

To put it into context, the phrase was like this:

"The Old Testament, unlike the New Testament, many times is not ___" The guy argued that many actions of people in the Old Testament were not to be considered as a moral example.

Thanks

Comment: https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/reverence

Answer (score -1):

**moral principle**

> *noun*. *1* The principles of right and wrong that are accepted by an individual
>   or a social group

In your case, the sentence would be

> The Old Testament, unlike the New Testament, many times is not [a] **moral principle**

Definition from [The Farlex Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/moral+principle)